# Why use the complicated formula to rotate a point instead of just $x=x\cos(deg)$ and $y=y\sin(deg)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry, rotations

I apologize in advance for the silly question, but I'm wondering why one would promote the following formula for rotating a point

```
x = (x * cos(deg)) + (y * sin(deg));
y = (x * sin(deg)) + (y * cos(deg));
```

when we can use this one, which is obviously simpler:

```
x = x * cos(deg);
y = y * sin(deg);
```

What are the reasons why most people would prefer the first formula over the second one?

Comment: The second formula is not true. It only works for some special x,y,deg values.

Comment: Take x=0, y=1. This doesn't rotate, it just goes up and down.

Comment: Given an angle "deg", this formula is also a linear map on $X \times Y$, and the reason this doesn't work has to do with the kernel of of the map being nonzero.

Comment: What the simpler version does is it maps the square with vertices $(\pm1,\pm1)$ to a rectangle inscribed in the unit circle. The $x$ and $y$ axes never rotate, they just shrink. You do get some changes in the direction from the origin to points in the first quadrant (for example), but the effect in the second quadrant is a mirror-image of the effect in the first quadrant.

Comment: By the way, as presented in the question, **both sets of formulas are wrong**. They are nonsensical as mathematical formulas, because $x$ means the same thing on both sides of an $=$ sign (you don't signify "old" $x$ just by putting it on the right and "new" $x$ just by putting it on the left; you actually have to use different names for the old and new values). They don't work as chunks of a computer program either; in the second case because you get nothing like a true rotation, and in the first case because by the time you get to the second line you have already changed the value of $x$.

Comment: Also you really need to be aware that most computer math libraries assume the inputs to the trig functions are in radians, **not** degrees. Writing `sin(deg)` looks like you are setting yourself up for failure no matter whether you use a good formula or a bad one.

Comment: In addition to all the problems noted in the previous comments, you're also missing a minus sign in one of your two formulas.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! ... If you calculate $x^2+y^2$ for a point and its ostensible rotation about the origin, you should get identical values (for any angle). This works for (a corrected version of) the first equations, but not for the second. (Try it!) So, that should suggest why most people might prefer to *not* use those second equations. :) ... In any case, please [edit your question](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4156125/edit) to describe what makes/made you think that the second equations work. We may be able to address important misconceptions.